# How to get search button inside input field in mdbootstrap ?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I trying to do the following for getting the search button inside the input field with class input-ol, but its not working. I am writing the following code.

```
<form id="search_form" onsubmit="return false;">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="input-ol" name="query" placeholder="Ex: cars, watches, exercise... "/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn" onclick="return searchcontent()">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" aria-label="Search">
                            <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
</form>
```

[The output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve8Ee.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the class `form-control` to your input element to get it to work.

```css
.input-group input.input-ol {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

button.rounded {
  border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <form id="search_form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-ol form-control" name="query" placeholder="Ex: cars, watches, exercise... " />
        <span class="input-group-btn" onclick="return searchcontent()">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-primary rounded" type="button" aria-label="Search">
            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
           </button>
         </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also removed the class `fa-2x` from the icon element just to make the snippet work, but if you have additional styles that make the larger button work with your input field you probably won't have to remove that class.

Comment: Hi i used the same snippet but my output looks like following:

Comment: Did you mean to post a link?

Comment: Hi, I used the same code you used but the input-ol makes the input rounded as the image i attached, and the button is added at the end of it? is there anyway I can get it inside?

Comment: Is input-ol a custom class? I don't see it defined anywhere in Bootstrap.

Comment: I just updated my answer to round the input to look like yours, and then round the left two corners of the button to match. If there are still alignment issues I would need to see the css for input-ol.

Comment: .search-blk .input-ol {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 530px;
 height: 47px;
 border-radius: 24px !important;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 0 3px;
 float: left;
}

Comment: This is the custom css used for input-ol